# SQL PHP search asking for at least one word

Tags: php, sql, search

I am trying to make a search form with php, using the following query :

```
$this->images('`description`="'.db::escape($mysearch).'"');
```

It's working great, BUT it returns only the EXACT description that corresponds to $mysearch !
I would like that it returns all the descriptions that contains the keywords (1, 2 or 3) from the $mysearch field.
 What is the exact SQL query ? I tried with :

```
'MATCH `description` AGAINST "'.db::escape($mysearch).'"'
```

But I get an error back:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'MATCH `title` AGAINST "mykeyword"' at line 1

The solution was :

```
'MATCH(title) AGAINST ("'.db::escape($keyword).'" IN BOOLEAN MODE)'
```

Comment: What do you mean "But that's not working"?  Do you get an error message?  Do you simply get an empty result set?  It'd help to know which flavor of SQL you're using as well, as fulltext search capabilities are pretty unique to each db vendor.  Some hints on mysql fulltext can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125678/mysql-fulltext-not-working http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439416/fulltext-search-in-mysql-does-not-return-any-rows

Comment: Looks like proper match syntax is more like `MATCH(description) AGAINST ("'.db::escape($mysearch).'") '` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use explode:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php
on a space or comma as your delimiter, and then do a for each on the resulting array to add a line to the query for each string in that array.

For a pseudo example:

```
//input of the string
$input = "keyword1 keyword2 keyword3";
$inputArray = explode(" ",$input);
foreach ($inputArray as $keyword) {
  $sql .= " OR tableName.ColName like '%$keyword%'";
}
```

obviously clean it up and validate the input, preferable use prepared statements etc (looks like you are using some sort of ORM?), and hopefully the description column is relatively short and has an index on its full content, otherwise the query will be very slow.

Update: I realize you were attempting the syntax to use a fulltext index. If you have a MyISAM table, or a new enough version of mysql that supports fulltext indexes on InnoDB tables, then you might want to skip this solution I have offered as it WILL become very slow  once you have more records in teh table than will fit into memory / cache.  Unfortunately, I have never used a fulltext index and cannot help you there. I am switching to using Zend_Search_Lucene vs the solution I listed above. (http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.html)

Comment: I don't believe MySQL can use an index to optimize `like '%$keyword%'`, so you end up with a sequential scan.

Comment: Frank Farmer is right, if you do a like '%keyword%' no index is used, if you do a like 'keyword%' then it is used. big speed difference for larger tables.